# Evaluate/Find column delimiter of a text file

Tags: c#, ssis, delimiter

Does anybody have a good method of evaluating/finding the column delimiter of a given text file? I'm willing to any suggestions, whether that involves C# script, Powerscript, etc.

I have a client who likes to keep us on our feet by changing column delimiters nearly every other data feed. This obviously, breaks our SQL agent import jobs. While I could go the failure route -- if this connection manager (with comma delimiter for instance) fails, use another connection manager (tab delimited connection) -- but I would much rather evaluate the delimiter before the failure and decide which route to take. Anybody have any experience doing this?

Comment: If you have a client changing input at random just increase your billing hours for software modifications. But to you question, I don't think a script can "guess" what is the delimiter just seeing the text. You need decide a protocol with your client. For example if a name field have `Samuel, Jhon `  you can't use `,`  as separator. Because that can be a field Name or two fields Name and LastName

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each row has the same number of columns, you could always pick a set of common delimiters (comma, tab, pipe, whatever) and count how many of each are within the first so many rows. If the comma counts for the first 5 rows is `34,34,35,34,36` while the tab count for those rows is `0,0,1,0,0` then you probably have 34 comma-delimited columns, with a few extra commas embedded in text. It'll be easier if you know in advance how many columns to expect.

Bottom line is it may not be a deterministic, black-and-white algorithm, but a matter of choosing some rules and thresholds based on what the data usually looks like and then having your code make a best guess.

That, or put the smack down on the client. :-)